# When using SQL table variable as input parameter to stored procedure,Entity framework Get Column Information doesn't return column information

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am using SQL table variable as input parameter to stored procedure and returning some column in stored procedure.But in entity framework **Edit Function Import** dialog when i was clicking on **Get Column Information** option it shows **The selected stored procedure and function returns no column**.But when i removed table variable as input parameter it returning all column properly.Below is SP Code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_TEST]
(
    @TV_TEST DBO.[TV_TEST] READONLY,
    @ID_SESSION  Varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Select '89834343'as Mobile,'123' as Message_Code;
END
```

I tried SET FMTONLY OFF option also.

Answer (score 0):

SQL  `SET FMTONLY OFF` is set to OFF by default, try `SET FMTONLY ON`